# Is it possible to set default geopoint in the sanity.io?

Tags: sanity

I have a field:

```
{
  name: 'location',
  title: 'Map',
  type: 'geopoint'
}
```

and I use `@sanity/google-maps-input`. It is great, but default localization is New York. How can I change it to another location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible in the file `config/@sanity/google-maps-input.json`

```js
{
  "apiKey": "XYZ",
  "defaultZoom": 11,
  "defaultLocation": {
    "lat": 40.7058254,
    "lng": -74.1180863
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad you found out! Note that this default only applies to the map when _displayed_ in studio. The `defaultLocation` you specify here will not be stored on documents in the datastore.